# unable to set fixed position for a DOM element using Html Service

Tags: position, google-apps-script, fixed

I created a script to publish the following html page using Html Service:

```
<html>
  <div id="fixeddiv"></div>
  <script>
    var div=document.getElementById("fixeddiv");
    div.style.position="fixed";
    alert(div.style.position);
  </script>
</html>
```

The alert window shows an empty string.
Isn't possible to set a fixed position for a `div` element?

Comment: Using the new `IFRAME` sandBox mode allows a fixed element.  Use this code: `HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME`  [Google Documentation - Sandbox Mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same thing and the answer appears to be NO.  Apparently they're worried fixed divs are a security exposure.

Next thing they'll be wanting to remove the keys from our keyboards too  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I used this to get a 'fixed' effect for a global navbar at the top. It might be of use to you or others.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        $( '.fixed' ).css('top', $( this ).scrollTop());
    });
});
```

Note: in GAS the $( window ).scroll() wasn't working for me so I instead created a div block the size of the view port with a scroll bar overflow and used that instead.

Comment: Nice solution. I created the div and using the $(window) selector it works. But at some point the div scroll stopped and the window scroll starts to work. At that moment the "fixed" element goes out of the screen partially. Do you know how to fix it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I've found another 'solution' for this:

I created 2 divs, fixedHeader and content

```
<div id="fixedHeader"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

The css code, where we set #fixedHeader to be always on top and for #content we set a padding-top matching the height of #fixedHeader so the elements won't get under #fixedHeader:

```
#fixedHeader {position:absolute; top:0;}
#content {padding-top:50px; overflow:auto;}
```

And finally javascript to make #contet match the height of the viewport when document loads:

```
$(function(){ $("#content").css('height',window.innerHeight); }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: What sandbox mode are you using? NATIVE, IFRAME?

Comment: I am using the default one (NATIVE). I didn't know there were different types. And you're right, IFRAME mode supports fixed position so my answer is totally worthless now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `position:fixed` is not allowed due to security concerns: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1840